# Nim: How to dynamically define a Slice that can be either forwards of backwards?

Tags: types, slice, nim-lang

I would like to dynamically define a `Slice`, that can either be based on forwards or backwards indices (depending on whether its start position is given as a positive or negative number).

I'm trying things on https://play.nim-lang.org/

I tried a union type as follows:

```
type mySlice = Slice[BackwardsIndex] | Slice[int]
var sl: mySlice
let s = "1234567890"
let bcStart = 3
let bcLen = 3
if bcLen < 0:
  sl = (bcStart-1)..<(bcStart+bcLen-1)
else:
  sl = ^(bcStart+bcLen-1)..^(bcStart)
echo s[sl]
```

This fails with `/usercode/in.nim(2, 5) Error: invalid type: 'mySlice' for var`.

I tried

```
let s = "1234567890"
let bcStart = 3
let bcLen = 3
if bcLen < 0:
  let sl = (bcStart-1)..<(bcStart+bcLen-1)
else:
  let sl = ^(bcStart+bcLen-1)..^(bcStart)
echo s[sl]
```

And this fails as follows:

```
/usercode/in.nim(5, 7) Hint: 'sl' is declared but not used [XDeclaredButNotUsed]
/usercode/in.nim(7, 7) Hint: 'sl' is declared but not used [XDeclaredButNotUsed]
/usercode/in.nim(8, 8) Error: undeclared identifier: 'sl'
```

And I also tried the following:

```
let s = "1234567890"
let bcStart = 3
let bcLen = 3
let sl =
  if bcLen < 0:
    (bcStart-1)..<(bcStart+bcLen-1)
  else:
    ^(bcStart+bcLen-1)..^(bcStart)
echo s[sl]
```

With yet a different way to fail:

```
/usercode/in.nim(8, 23) Error: type mismatch: got <HSlice[system.BackwardsIndex, system.BackwardsIndex]> but expected 'HSlice[system.int, system.int]'
```

**Why those failures, and how should I do?**

#### Edit (09/09/2020) Desired API

My use case is more complex than that, but it amounts to a command-line program that takes as arguments an input text, a "barcode" and a barcode start position, and it tells whether the barcode is present in the input text at the specified position. If the position is given as a negative int, it means that we specify a position from the end.

I have something working as expected:

```
$ cat src/test.nim
import docopt
from strutils import parseInt

# https://github.com/docopt/docopt.nim
const doc = """

Usage:
  test -t <input_text> -b <barcode> -s <barcode_start>

-h --help                                 Show this help message and exit.
-t --input_text <input_text>              Text in which to search for the barcode.
-b --barcode <barcode>                    Barcode to search.
-s --barcode_start <barcode_start>        Position at which the barcode starts (1-based), negative if from end.
"""

proc match_text(inText: string, barcode: string, bcStart: int): bool =
  var
    bcSeq: string
    bcLen: int = barcode.len
  if bcStart < 0:
    bcSeq = inText[^(bcLen - bcStart - 1)..^(-bcStart)]
  else:
    bcSeq = inText[(bcStart-1)..<(bcStart + bcLen - 1)]
  if bcSeq == barcode:
    result = true
  else:
    result = false

when isMainModule:
  let args = docopt(doc)
  var
    barcode: string
    inText: string
    bcStart: int
  for opt, val in args.pairs():
    case opt
    of "-t", "--input_text":
      inText = $args[opt]
    of "-b", "--barcode":
      barcode = $args[opt]
    of "-s", "--barcode_start":
      bcStart = parseInt($val)
    else:
      echo "Unknown option" & opt
      quit(QuitFailure)
  if match_text(inText, barcode, bcStart):
    echo "Matches"
  else:
    echo "Doesn't match"
```

Building works:

```
$ nimble build
# [successful build output]
```

Testing works:

```
$ ./bin/test -t aacgttb -b aa -s 1
Matches
$ ./bin/test -t aacgttb -b aa -s 2
Doesn't match
$ ./bin/test -t aacgttb -b tt -s -1
Doesn't match
$ ./bin/test -t aacgttb -b tt -s -2
Matches
```

However, **in my real application, I'm re-using the same slicing several times in different pieces of text, so I would like to define a `Slice` object that I can re-use instead of repeatedly computing the slice "in-place"**.

Comment: Can you give examples on the API that you are trying to achieve (it is not clear to me by the examples posted)?

Comment: @pietroppeter Sorry for my delayed reaction. I added an example API I would like to achieve (rather: that I actually achieve, but I would like to "optimize" the internal implementation).

Comment: Can you just use the HSlice object? let mySlice = (bcStart-1)..<(bcStart + bcLen - 1)

Comment: I do not think a Slice[T] generic type (or HSlide[T, U]) can be used here, since at compile time he will not know whether T is int or BackwardsIndex. below I update my answer arguing that one should just avoid thinking in terms of slices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issues are all related to the fact that your type is a [Type Class](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#generics-type-classes). This is a pseudo type that can only be used at compile time as a parameter for proc overload (or for `is` operator). In particular it cannot be assigned to a `var` (the first error you report) and it cannot be used dynamically at run time.

The other 2 errors you get are due to 1) the fact that `s1` is not defined outside of if scope. 2) The fact that the compiler wants a unique type for `s1` (it infers type from first if and then enforces for the else clause).

[Object variants](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-object-variants) (also Sum types, Algebraic Data types in Nim; terminology [Union Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) is not often used in Nim) are usually the most straightforward way to implement dynamic types in Nim (classic example is JsonNode).

## Edit: on desired API

Since the emphasis is on reusability of "Slice" and performance improvement, the following (also here: https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2wXp) might be used:

```
type myPattern = object
  barcode: string
  start: int
  isBackwards: bool

proc initMyPattern(barcode: string, bcStart: int): myPattern =
  # no need to have a new variable for barcode.len since it is already available (not computed) for a string
  # also no need to precompute last index of slice because it will not be used
  if bcStart < 0:
    myPattern(barcode: barcode, start: barcode.len - bcStart - 1, isBackwards: true)
  else:
    myPattern(barcode: barcode, start: bcStart - 1, isBackwards: false)


proc startIndex(inText: string, p: myPattern): int =
  if p.isBackwards:
    # this cannot be precomputed if len of inText is variable
    inText.len - p.start
  else:
    p.start
   
proc match(inText: string, p: myPattern): bool =
  var
    i =  startIndex(inText, p)
    j = 0
  # case where inText is not long enough to match
  if i + p.barcode.len - 1 >= inText.len:
    return false
  # instead of computing the slice of inText (which allocates a new string), we directly iterate over indices
  while j < p.barcode.len:
    if p.barcode[j] != inText[i]:
      return false
    inc i
    inc j
  return true

assert "aacgttb".match initMyPattern("aa", 1)
assert not "aacgttb".match initMyPattern("aa", 2)
assert not "aacgttb".match initMyPattern("tt", -1)
assert "aacgttb".match initMyPattern("tt", -2)
assert not "aacgttb".match initMyPattern("ttbb", -2)
echo "tests successful"
```

Remarks:

- I assume fixed `barcode_start` and `barcode` need to be matched multiple times against different texts (possibly of variable length)
- it is better to avoid computing the "slice" of a string, since it allocates a new string (see [here](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/version-1-2/lib/system.nim#L2438)). I suspect this to be a bigger performance improvement than the precomputation of start index.
- by previous two points, the object to be "compiled" before applying match multiple times is not really a Slice (hence the name myPattern)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer(s). I would say YXZ problem, actually: My simplification did not capture accurately my real use case. Just matching was an oversimplification I thought of in order to have something to "justify" the slice extraction, but in my real use case, after extracting the piece of text using the slice, I do more stuff than just checking it matches the barcode. I pass it to a function that computes a distance to the barcode, for instance, so I need to access to the full slice of text.

Comment: But maybe I can implement everything I want using (full) loops on the original  text, if this has good chances of being more efficient than allocating a new string.

Answer (score 3):

the expression

```
let sl = if (bcLen >0): bcLen else: BackwardsIndex(bcLen)#Error: type mismatch!
```

can't compile in a staticly typed language, so you need to box `sl` using inheritance or a Variant

and then unbox again when producing the slice.  You might do that like so:

```
type
  PosOrNegKind = enum
    Pos,Neg
  PosOrNeg = object
    case kind:PosOrNegKind
    of Pos: posVal:int
    of Neg: negVal:int
  mySlice = object
    beg,fin:PosOrNeg

proc `[]`(str:string,sl:mySlice):string =
  let beg = case sl.beg.kind
    of Pos: sl.beg.posVal
    of Neg: len(str) + sl.beg.negVal
  let fin = case sl.fin.kind
    of Pos: sl.fin.posVal
    of Neg: len(str) + sl.fin.negVal
  str[beg .. fin]

proc posOrNeg(x:int):PosOrNeg =
  if (x >= 0): PosOrNeg(kind: Pos, posVal: x)
  else:       PosOrNeg(kind: Neg, negVal: x)

proc createSlice(beg,fin:int):mySlice =
  result.beg = posOrNeg(beg)
  result.fin = posOrNeg(fin)

let sl = createSlice(3,-3)
echo s[sl]# "34567"
```

but for this particular use case you've got a natural discriminator in the value itself (whether the int is positive or negative) so you can just do:

```
type
  MySlice = object
    a,b:int

proc `--`(a,b:int):MySlice = MySlice(a: a, b: b)

proc `[]`(s:string,m:MySlice):string =
  var beg = if (m.a < 0): s.len + m.a else: m.a 
  var fin = if (m.b < 0): s.len + m.b else: m.b
  
  #safety checks
  if fin < beg: return ""
  if fin >= s.len: fin = s.len - 1
  if beg < 0: beg = 0

  s[beg..fin]
  
echo s[3 -- 5] #  "345"
echo s[3 -- -2] # "345678"
echo s[-5 -- 9] # "56789"
echo s[-8 -- -2] # "2345678"
echo s[-1 -- 1] #  ""
```

**Edit**
You wanted to be able to pass around a Slice that could be used on different input strings.  Here's how that would look with the above:

```
#fixing off-by-one errors left as an exercise for the reader 
proc make_slice(barcode:string,bcStart:int):mySlice=
  let bcLen = barcode.len
  if bcStart < 0:
    (bcStart - bcLen) -- bcStart
  else:
    bcStart -- (bcStart + bcLen)

let sl = make_slice("abaca", -3)
for inText in @["abacus","abacadacaba","abracadabra"]:
  if inText[sl] == barcode:
    echo "matches"
```

Comment: If the final lines are the type of API OP wanted to achieve, I fail to see what would be the advantage over the standard syntax (e.g. `echo[^5 .. 9]`, all but last line would compile fine). Nice answer though :)

Comment: Oh I actively disrecommend its use.  but hopefully it shows that adding desired syntax is quite elegant in Nim.